# Left Join, but use record only once

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join

Here goes my issue.
I have a transaction table where we store all transactions for all accounts (huge table-153M rows). A negative transaction can offset a positive transaction if their offset code matches.

The issue is one negative tran can only offset the oldest positive tran with the same offset code. Only way I can think of is to loop through all negative transactions and start inserting matching positive into a temp table. Then join the temp table in the loop to avoid duplicate.

I don't think it is a good idea to run a loop in a table like this big, but I cannot think of any other elegant way to achieve what I want.

It is kind of hard to explain, so below is a simplified table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TBL
CREATE TABLE #TBL
(TranID TinyInt, TranDT Date, OffsetCode CHAR(1), NegTran Bit)
INSERT #TBL VALUES
(1,'4/1/2020','A',0)
,(2,'4/2/2020','A',0)
,(3,'4/3/2020','A',0)
,(4,'4/4/2020','B',0)
,(5,'4/5/2020','B',0)
,(6,'4/6/2020','B',0)
,(7,'4/7/2020','B',1)
,(8,'4/8/2020','B',1)
,(9,'4/9/2020','A',1)
,(10,'4/10/2020','A',1)
```

Eventually What I want to see is below

```
TranID  TranDT      OffsetCode   NegTran   TranID TranDT      OffsetCode NegTran
7       2020-04-07  B            1         4      2020-04-04  B          0
8       2020-04-08  B            1         5      2020-04-05  B          0
9       2020-04-09  A            1         1      2020-04-01  A          0
10      2020-04-10  A            1         2      2020-04-02  A          0
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Your expected output appears to have a typo.  Date `2020-04-09` has an offset code of A, not B.

Comment: Transaction '9' should be 'B'?

Comment: Still 'A' in transaction 9.

Comment: Sorry. Updated again. Tran9 is A. should be joined with Tran1 as it is the oldest offsetcode A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this using `row_number()` and either conditional aggregation or a `join`.

```
select max(case when negtran = 1 then tranid end),
       max(case when negtran = 1 then trandt end),
       offsetcode, 
       max(case when negtran = 1 then 1 else 0 end),
       max(case when negtran = 0 then tranid end),
       max(case when negtran = 0 then trandt end),
       offsetcode, 
       max(case when negtran = 0 then 1 else 0 end)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by negtran, offsetcode order by trandt) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by offsetcode, seqnum
```

Comment: Couldn't find any case where this solution can't work. And way shorter than mine! +1.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I will give it a try in a real table. I have a lot more criteria to add which makes it much more complex, but I get the idea.